# Адаптивные блоки на 50% высоты

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

К примеру есть такая html-разметка:

```
<div class='wrap'>
 <div class='nav'></div>
 <div class='section>
  <div class='section__top'>

   <div class='section__top__item><img></div>
   <div class='section__top__item><img></div>
   <div class='section__top__item><img></div>
  </div>

  <div class='section__bottom>
   <div class='section__bottom__item> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

При этом изображения в блоках верхней секции тоже должны растягиваться на высоту родителя . 
Как сделать так, чтобы **.nav** блок занимал 10% ширины и был всегда на всю высоту окна браузера, а **.section__bottom .section__top**, всегда занимали по 50% высоты окна браузера, не зависимо от разрешения экрана ?
И возможно ли это сделать без позиционирования, чтобы было больше статики с переходом в адаптивность  ?

Comment: а что вы понимаете под позиционированием? и какие альтернативы позиционированию вы знаете?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/1dmsp221/

Comment: Под позиционированием я понимаю свойства группы position.<br>
soledar10, спасибо, попробую, может поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav,
.section {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 10vw;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
}

.section {
  background: #ddd;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}

.section__top,
.section__bottom {
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.section__bottom {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='nav'>nav</div>
  <div class='section'>
    <div class='section__top'>
      section__top
    </div>
    <div class='section__bottom'>
      section__bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает )